# How to print without opening print dialog box in edge browser using java script?

Tags: javascript, printing, printf

I need to send my html page directly to printer without opening print dialog box in edge browser using java script. Any one could you please help me?

Comment: what do you mean by "print" and "opening print dialog box"?

Comment: I need to send my html page directly to printer without opening print dialog box in edge browser using java script.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/366012/how-to-bypass-web-browser-print-preview-and-any-pr.html etc. In general, AFAIK, this is disallowed, for good reason.